# Overriding equals and hashcode?

Tags: java

I have a set of Car where class Car is as follows:

```
public class Car{

    private Tyre tyre;

    private Engine engine;

}
```

In order to use Set for car for avoiding duplicates, I need to override hashcode and equals for Car class. My questions is do I also need to implement equals and hashcode for Tyre and Engine class?

Comment: If using eclipse you can right click in your source page, go to Source, then Generate hashCode() and equals(). Do this for all classes you need them in. You can then edit if you feel the need.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't.

If the equality of two `Car`s *depends* on the equality of the `Tyre`s and `Engine`s those cars have, then implementing `equals` and `hashCode` methods for the `Tyre` and `Engine` classes and delegating to them from `Car`'s `equals` and `hashCode` methods is probably a very good idea. But if `Car` equality is determined some other way (like a car id, for example), then it might make perfect sense not to have `equals` or `hashCode` methods for `Tyre` and `Engine`.

Answer (score 2):

If you will be using the `hashCode` results for your `tyre` and `engine` in the `hashCode` method for `Car`, then you will need to override `hashCode` in `Tyre` and `Engine` also.  If you will be using the `equals` results for your `tyre` and `engine` in the `equals` method for `Car`, then you will need to override `equals` in `Tyre` and `Engine` also.